# argument of type 'unsigned int' is incompatible with parameter of type 'time_t' c++ error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-cast, srand

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    srand(time(static_cast<unsigned>(0)));

    std::cout << "Hello from game 4!" << "\n";

    system("PAUSE"); // end of application

    return 0;
}
```

I got the error:

```
argument of type `"unsigned int" is incompatible with the parameter of type "time_t*"
```

I'm following a simple C++ tutorial as I am a beginner.

Comment: What is your compiler/IDE/OS etc.?

Comment: Function `time` does not take an integer. Why do you provide one? The compiler is right. [Time takes a pointer](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html): `time_t time(time_t *tloc);`

Comment: If that tutorial contains such erroneous code, drop it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of the function that you are calling:

> ```
> std::time_t time( std::time_t* arg );
> ```

The parameter is a `std::time_t*` which is a pointer type.

> ```
> srand(time(static_cast<unsigned>(0)));
> ```

It doesn't make sense to pass `static_cast<unsigned>(0)` as an argument when a pointer is expected. Prior to C++11 that would have worked and the argument would have been interpreted as a null pointer, although it is highly confusing.

Since C++11, that hasn't been allowed anymore. You can achieve the same like this:

```
std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
```

---

> Im following a simple c++ tutorial

The tutorial that you follow is apparently outdated (by about a decade), and it wasn't of high quality even when it was written.

Comment: @RemyLebeau C++03 says: `A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. - An integral constant-expression can involve only literals of arithmetic types ... Only type conversions to integral or enumeration types can be used.` - `static_cast<unsigned>(0)` involves only a literal of arithmetic type and a conversion to integral type. It is an integral constant expression rvalue. If a C++03 compiler doesn't accept it as a null pointer constant, then it doesn't conform to the standard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I can introduce you to a few recent compilers that do allow it: [GCC, Clang, MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/c5xMajaq6)

Comment: I use G++ compiler on visual studio 2022